# Why does `selectperm!` do a different thing than `selectperm`?

Tags: sorting, julia, permutation

I want to use `selectperm` in a loop, to do something based on the indices of the `t` smallest elements in each column of a matrix (say `t = 3` here):

```
julia> a = rand(10, 10);
julia> for i in indices(a, 2)
         println(selectperm(view(a, :, i), 1:3))
       end
[9, 7, 6]
[3, 2, 6]
[8, 3, 1]
[4, 7, 6]
[4, 9, 10]
[6, 10, 8]
[10, 8, 9]
[10, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 9]
[5, 8, 10]
```

Thinking that allocating the index vector every time would be better avoided (I don't use them for printing, in reality), I tried using a preallocated array for the result -- but that returns completely different values:

```
julia> cache = Vector{Int}(3);
julia> for i in indices(a, 2)
           selectperm!(cache, view(a, :, i), 1:3)
           println(cache)
       end
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 2]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
```

So, what's happening here? How do I use `selectperm!` corretly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat unusually for functions with a `!`, the "preallocated index vector" argument of `selectperm!` is *not* the place where the result is stored -- or at least, not only it.  This argument gets used internally to create a partial permuatation of *all* indices, which is then *subindexed* with the given `k` argument which describes the indices you want to select (in our case `1:3` for the three smallest).  This is rather easily seen from the [code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/d386e40c17d43b79fc89d3e579fc04547241787c/base/sort.jl#L553).  That the result looked reasonable but wrong here is merely an accident; the following would have been more revealing:

```
julia> cache = Vector{Int}(3);
julia> for i in indices(a, 2)
           selectperm!(cache, view(a, :, i), 4:6)
           println(cache)
       end
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 3-element Array{Int64,1} at index [4:6]
Stacktrace: <...>
```

So, to utilize that here, we have to preallocate a vector containing *all* indices in question (that is, of a column of `a`), and then that index vector will be permuted every time.  Additionally passing `initialized = true` avoids filling up the indices each time.

```
julia> cache = collect(indices(a, 2));
julia> for i in indices(a, 2)
           ix = selectperm!(cache, view(a, :, i), 1:3, initialized = true)
           println(ix)
       end
[9, 7, 6]
[3, 2, 6]
[8, 3, 1]
[4, 7, 6]
[4, 9, 10]
[6, 10, 8]
[10, 8, 9]
[10, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 9]
[5, 8, 10]
```